# Ref is of type undefined inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, ref

I have this component which is trying to render a chart:

```
export default function Chart({ inputCurrency, outputCurrency, period }: ChartProps) {
  ....

  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = createChart(ref.current, { width: 400, height: 300 })

  }, [candleData])

  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

However, I get an error saying ref is of type `undefined`:

```
Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLElement'.  TS2345

    30 |
    31 |   useEffect(() => {
  > 32 |     const chart = createChart(ref.current, { width: 400, height: 300 })
       |                               ^
    33 |     const candlestickSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries()
    34 |     candlestickSeries.setData(candleData)
    35 |   }, [])
```

Also tried CertainPerformance's suggestion:

```
export default function Chart({ inputCurrency, outputCurrency, period }: ChartProps) {
  ....

  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement | undefined>()
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = createChart(ref.current!, { width: 400, height: 300 })
  }, [candleData])
  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

But got this error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLElement | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.  TS2322

    104 |   }, [candleData])
    105 |
  > 106 |   return <div ref={ref} id="chart" />
        |               ^
    107 | }
    108 |
```

Comment: Try `const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null)`

Comment: Getting `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLElement'.  TS2345` 
 @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate to TypeScript that the ref will be of type HTMLElement (or undefined), at the time of ref creation:

```
export default function Chart({ inputCurrency, outputCurrency, period }: ChartProps) {
  ....

  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement | undefined>()
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = createChart(ref.current!, { width: 400, height: 300 })
  }, [candleData])
  return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

Comment: I just tried it but got an error. Updated my original post with the error